# Refresh ListView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to refreshing my ListView when I deleted all Items. When the delete function is called, the sqlite-tables are cleared. this part works fine. But I can't refresh the listView. I tried notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidate(), but nothing works.

Any ideas?

```
public class ResultsAdapter 
        extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ResultsTypeOneOpenHelper    resultsTypeOne_db;
    private ResultsTypeTwoOpenHelper    resultsTypeTwo_db;
    private ResultsTypeThreeOpenHelper  resultsTypeThree_db;


    private ArrayList<Object> results;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }

    public ResultsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        resultsTypeOne_db = new ResultsTypeOneOpenHelper(context);
        resultsTypeTwo_db = new ResultsTypeTwoOpenHelper(context);
        resultsTypeThree_db = new ResultsTypethreeOpenHelper(context);
        results = new ArrayList<Object>();

        /* get results from sqlite */
        if (resultsTypeOne_db.getRowCount() != 0) {
            results.addAll( resultsTypeOne_db.getAllTypeOneResults() );
        }
        if (resultsTypeTwo_db.getRowCount() != 0) {
            results.addAll( resultsTypeTwo_db.getAllTypeTwoResults() );
        }
        if (resultsTypeThree_db.getRowCount() != 0) {
            results.addAll( resultsTypeThree_db.getAllTypeThreeResults() );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return results.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Object item = results.get(position);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (rowView == null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results_list_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.results_list_textView);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.text.setText( results.get(position).toString() );

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually changing the value of your `ArrayList` `results` ?

Comment: it looks like you are populating the `results` list by yourself, make sure you clear it before you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (which is the correct function to update the Adapter)

Comment: @x4rf41 you're right. I forgot to clear the ArrayList 'results'.

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `setListAdapter` on the `ListActivity` again. When all the items are deleted, call the `setListAdapter` method of `ListActivity` / `setAdapter` method on `ListView` if you are using `Activity` and not `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting data, first clear your ArrayList and then again get your new data and store it in ArrayList then after use ListView method setListAdapter(adapter)

Answer (score 0):

in your case. create method in `ResultsAdapter`  class like:

```
public void refreshadapter(Context context){

resultsTypeOne_db = new ResultsTypeOneOpenHelper(context);
        resultsTypeTwo_db = new ResultsTypeTwoOpenHelper(context);
        resultsTypeThree_db = new ResultsTypethreeOpenHelper(context);
        results.clear();

        /* get results from sqlite */
        if (resultsTypeOne_db.getRowCount() != 0) {
            results.addAll( resultsTypeOne_db.getAllTypeOneResults() );
        }
        if (resultsTypeTwo_db.getRowCount() != 0) {
            results.addAll( resultsTypeTwo_db.getAllTypeTwoResults() );
        }
        if (resultsTypeThree_db.getRowCount() != 0) {
            results.addAll( resultsTypeThree_db.getAllTypeThreeResults() );
        }
}
```

call this method from your activity

you need object for call this method which you have already when you do `setAdapter()`

so, call using..

```
reslutAdapter.refreshadapter(myActivity.this);
reslutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```